# Как получить размер pushButton. который находится в layout`е?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qpushbutton, qlayout, qsizepolicy

Я использую кнопку как кликабельное изображение. Я поместил её на `QVBoxLayout`, а этот `Layout` установил как основной на центральный виджет `centralwidget`.

Я запускаю приложение сразу в полноэкранном режиме (`.showFullScreen()`). Таким образом кнопка растягивается на весь экран. Но как я могу растянуть изображение(`icon`) по размеру кнопки?

Чтобы установить размер иконки по размеру кнопки я должен как-то узнать её текущий размер во время, когда окно открылось в полноэкранном режиме, но такой функции я не нашёл.

Подскажите как узнать текущий размер кнопки с учётом того, что при запуске программы она растягивается согласно `sizePolicy` по размеру окна или возможно есть функция, которая изменяет размер иконки автоматически?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пожалуйста всегда предоставляйте минимально-воспроизводимый пример, который демонстрирует проблему.

Возможный вариант может выглядеть примерно так:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *

        
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.сentralWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
        self.сentralWidget.setObjectName("сentralWidget")
        self.сentralWidget.setStyleSheet(
            "#сentralWidget {background-color: #347474;}")
        self.setCentralWidget(self.сentralWidget) 
        self.resize(500, 500)

        self.pushButton = QPushButton()   
        self.pushButton.setIcon(QIcon('13.png'))       
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Minimum, QSizePolicy.Minimum) 
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet('''
            QPushButton {
                border: 1px solid transparent;
                border-radius: 2px;
            }
            QPushButton:hover {
                border-color: darkGray;
                background: lightGray;
            }
                QPushButton:pressed {
                background: darkGray;
            }
        ''')        
        self.pushButton.setCheckable(True)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.on_clicked)

        layout = QGridLayout(self.сentralWidget)
        layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        layout.setSpacing(0)
        
        layout.addWidget(self.pushButton, 0, 0) #, alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)
        
        self.label_right = QLabel('label_right', alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_right.setObjectName("label_right")
        self.label_right.setStyleSheet("#label_right {background-color: #ED8240;}")
        self.label_right.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Minimum, QSizePolicy.Minimum)        
        layout.addWidget(self.label_right, 0, 1)
        
        self.label_bottom = QLabel('label_bottom', alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_bottom.setObjectName("label_bottom")
        self.label_bottom.setStyleSheet(
            "#label_bottom {background-color: #801336; color: #fff;}")
        self.label_bottom.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Minimum, QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        layout.addWidget(self.label_bottom, 1, 0, 1, 2) #, alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)

    def on_clicked(self, status):
        if status:
            self.showNormal() 
        else:
            self.showFullScreen()          

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        self.pushButton.setIconSize(
            QSize(event.size().width()-150, 
            event.size().height()-50) 
        )
        self.pushButton.setIconSize(
           QSize(self.size().width()//2-10, self.size().height()//2-10))
        super().resizeEvent(event)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.showFullScreen()
#    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**13.png**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]